# IEnumerable - foreach - The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public static string ConvertParamToHTMLString(
                            IEnumerable<GetParm_Result> paramList)
{
    foreach (GetParm_Result result in paramList.ToList())
    {
      ...
      ...
    }
}
```

I am getting the following message when it tries to execute the foreach:

> The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once.

I thought that the ToList() would resolve this issue..

Comment: Are you perhaps calling `ToList` (or any other method that would iterate the query) somewhere else in that method, or are you iterating that sequence before even passing it into the method?

Comment: Where did `paramList` come from? Did you already evaluate it before passing it to the function?

Comment: Yes, I already evaluted it.

Comment: Why even convert to a list to begin with? You can iterate over the `IEnumerable` so to me, it looks like the `ToList()` is just a needless operation.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal If it's a sequence that can't be iterated multiple times a valid solution is to convert it to a list and then iterate that list multiple times.

Comment: @NatePet `ToList()` has to evaluate the IEnumerable in order to convert it to a list. You need to make `ToList` your first and only evaluation, then pass the List around instead.

Comment: @Servy yeah but he doesn't assign it to a local variable. I could be wrong but I'm pretty sure the only thing his `ToList()` call is doing is making his code perform worse.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal That is correct.  [Hence my original clarifying question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18090223/ienumerable-foreach-the-result-of-a-query-cannot-be-enumerated-more-than-onc/18090293?noredirect=1#comment26479576_18090223)

Comment: Are you sure the message actually comes from this code? It doesn't seem possible. What happens in the foreach loop? Do you access the IEnumerable there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `paramList.ToList()` once and put it in a variable, then enumerate on the variable:

```
var list = paramList.ToList();
foreach(var result in list) ...
foreach(var result in list) ...   // No error here
```

Comment: note that the code in the question doesn't have two foreach loops.  This may be the problem (in which case the question needs to be changed) or it could be a different problem that this wouldn't address.

Comment: I noticed it doesn't, it was just to demonstrate how this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only *show* one execution, I'm assuming you're executing the query (using `ToList`, `AsEnumerable`, or implicitly using `foreach`) before you call `ConvertParamToHTMLString`.  If that is the case, then you can just save the result in a variable and use it multiple times.  In fact, since your function already accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` you don't need to change that code at all!